# Density in Compact-Open Equivalent to containment of subbases

Tags: general-topology, continuity, function-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Hausdorff spaces and consider the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$.  Let $F\subseteq C(X,Y)$ be a non-empty subset and consider the topology $\tau$ on $C(X,Y)$ with subbase
$$
B_F\triangleq \{f\in F: f(K)\subseteq V\}_{K \mbox{ compact in X}, U \mbox{ open in Y}}.
$$

Is $F$ dense in $C(X,Y)$ with this topology?

Comment: It's nor arbitrary since it's used to generate this non-standard topology

Comment: Oh, you're taking $B_F$ as a subbase on $C(X,Y)$, not on $F$?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Instead of the larger sub-base which is typically used to form the compact-open topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Much more generally, let $Z$ be any set, let $F\subseteq Z$ be nonempty, let $B$ be a set of subsets of $F$, and let $\tau$ be the topology on $Z$ generated by $B$.  Then every element of $\tau$ is a union of finite intersections of elements of $B$.  All of the terms of such a union intersect $F$ unless they are empty, so any non-empty element of $\tau$ intersects $F$.  That is, $F$ is dense with respect to $\tau$.

Comment: Awesome!  
Also, I guess there's no reason to expect the topology in the question can be metrized. (if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is metric) (unlike the usual compact-open topology)

Comment: It is never metrizable unless $F$ is the whole space, since it will not even be $T_1$ (any open set containing a point not in $F$ must be the whole space).

Comment: Right, that's a good point.  Thanks for the help.  I'll have to think of how to modify the definition to get something at least Hausdorff

Comment: I've modified the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239431/follow-up-density-characterized-by-weak-topology

Comment: Last followup question, if $F$ was dense in the compact-open topology, then shouldn't the two topologies line up?

Comment: No, not at all.  As I said before, any $\tau$-open set containing a point not in $F$ must be the whole space.

Comment: True, I think I'm getting tired.  Thanks Again Eric.

Comment: @AIM_BLB I see that you have created the (function-spaces) tag. It might be useful to create at least some basic [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/function-spaces/info) to clarify the intended usage of the tag. (Is it meant for topics from general topology, functional analysis or both? What is relation to some existing tags, such as ([tag:lp-spaces])?)

Comment: That's a good idea (this is the first time I create a tag).  I put in some information :)