# Follow up: Density Characterized by Weak Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, function-spaces

*This question is a follow-up on: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239220/density-in-compact-open-equivalent-to-containment-of-subbases/3239383?noredirect=1#comment6663132_3239383).*

Let $F$ be a non-empty subset of $C(X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are Hausdorff (and for simplicity assume that $Y$ is metric).  Let $\tau$ be the weak topology on $X$ generated by $F$.  Let us denote $(X,\tau)$ by $\tilde{X}$ to avoid confusion.

- Is $F$ is dense in $C(\tilde{X},Y)$?

If this is indeed the case then it seems to me that $F$ is dense in $C(X,Y)$ if and only if $\tau$ generates the "original" topology on $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X=Y$ and let $F$ consist of just the identity map.  Then $\tau$ is just the original topology on $X$, but $F$ is not dense in $C(X,Y)$ in most cases.

Comment: Ah, good point.... back to the drawing board for me haha Thank Eric  You've been very helpful :)